# Semirings induced by symmetric monoidal categories with finite coproducts

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, monoidal-categories

A symmetric monoidal category with finite coproducts is by definition a symmetric monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,1,\dotsc)$ such that the underlying category $\mathcal{C}$ has finite coproducts (this includes an initial object $0$) with the property that $\otimes$ preserves finite coproducts in each variable. In other words, we have a distributive law
$$X \otimes (\bigoplus_{i \in I} Y_i) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} (X \otimes Y_i).$$
This is also known as a [finitary distributive symmetric monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+monoidal+category). Notice that to each symmetric monoidal category with finite coproducts we may associate a commutative [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring): The elements are the isomorphism classes of objects in $\mathcal{C}$. The addition is $[X] + [Y] := [X \oplus Y]$, the multiplication is $[X] \cdot [Y] := [X \otimes Y]$. The zero element is $[0]$, the multiplicative unit is $[1]$. To avoid set-theoretic issues, let us assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is [essentially small](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+category). As a consequence, we may think of symmetric monoidal categories with finite coproducts as a possible [categorification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vertical+categorification) of semirings.

A familar example is the symmetric monoidal category of vector bundles on a space $X$, which produces the semiring of isomorphism classes of vector bundles on $X$. If $X$ is a point, we see that the semiring associated to $\mathsf{FinSet}$ is $\mathbb{N}$.

Note, however, that not every commutative semiring arises from the construction above. Basically this is because we have agreed that the addition is not induced by some symmetric monoidal structure which distributes over $\otimes$, but rather from the coproduct. The coproduct satisfies $X \oplus Y \cong 0 \Rightarrow X \cong Y \cong 0$. It follows that in the associated semiring only $0$ has an additive inverse.

**Question.** How can we classify those commutative semirings which are induced by essentially small symmetric monoidal categories with finite coproducts?

Every commutative monoid with the property $a+b=0 \Rightarrow a=b=0$ arises from an essentially small category with finite coproducts, see [SE/834869](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834869). But it is not clear if we can use this here.

Comment: If you have a commutative semiring $(R, +, \cdot)$ that satisfies $a+b = 0 \Rightarrow a=b=0$, can't you just take an essentially small category $C$ realizing $(R,+)$, take a skeleton $\mathrm{Sk}(C)$ of it and define on $\mathrm{Sk}(C)$ the symmetric monoidal structure induced by $(R,\cdot)$? That is, $[x] \otimes [y] \colon= [x \cdot y]$ (where $[x]$ denotes the object in $\mathrm{Sk}(C)$ that is associated to the object $x \in R$)

Comment: @Arducode This does not define a functor for $\otimes$. Or how do you define the tensor product of morphisms? Also notice that it is required that the tensor product is distributive - this is not guaranteed by arbitrary isomorphisms, they have to be the canonical ones. Therefore I do not think that the skeleton will help us.